# How to change intellij Java IDE automatic formatting of code behaviour ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

This is the output of reformat code option from intellij (alt + command + L)

```
int i = Main.someRandomFuntion("arg1", 
                    "arg2", 
                    "arg3", "arg4", 
                    someRandomFunction2("arg1", 
                            "arg2"), 
                    "arg6");
```

and what i need this is

```
int i = Main.someRandomFuntion("arg1",
                               "arg2",
                               "arg3", "arg4",
                               someRandomFunction2("arg1",
                                                   "arg2"),
                               "arg6");
```

which is just more an aesthetic improvement.

Do intellij (I am using 15) support an option to tweak auto format option ?, if so How can i do it ?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted as it's not a setting that can be easily found and there isn't a lot of documentation surrounding parameter alignment.

Comment: IMHO the first one is much more aesthetically pleasant. Either way, it's better to stick with the defaults because you risk reformatting that piece of code any time a colleague of yours makes changes. The sad truth is that most people stick to defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Go to:

```
Editor > Code Style > Java
```

Click on the `Wrapping and Braces` tab, scroll down to `Method declaration parameters` and change the settings there to what you desire.

---

*Note*: I found these particular Settings a little glitchy when I was toggling them but you can usually get what you want with a couple of minutes of fiddling and testing.